# Question on a solution from Google python class day

Tags: python

Hey,
I'm trying to learn a bit about Python so I decided to follow Google's [tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/). Anyway I had a question regarding one of their solution for an exercise.

Where I did it like this way.

```
# E. Given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged
# list of all the elements in sorted order. You may modify the passed in lists.
# Ideally, the solution should work in "linear" time, making a single
# pass of both lists.
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
  # +++your code here+++
  return sorted(list1 + list2)
```

However they did it in a more complicated way. So is Google's solution quicker? Because I noticed in the comment lines that the solution should work in "linear" time, which mine probably isn't?

This is their solution

```
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  result = []
  # Look at the two lists so long as both are non-empty.
  # Take whichever element [0] is smaller.
  while len(list1) and len(list2):
    if list1[0] < list2[0]:
      result.append(list1.pop(0))
    else:
      result.append(list2.pop(0))

  # Now tack on what's left
  result.extend(list1)
  result.extend(list2)
  return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is not linear, but that doesn't mean it's slower.  Algorithmic complexity ("big-oh notation") is often only a rough guide and always only tells one part of the story.

However, theirs isn't linear either, though it may appear to be at first blush.  Popping from a list requires moving all later items, so popping from the front requires moving all remaining elements.

It is a good exercise to think about how to make this O(n).  The below is in the same spirit as the given solution, but avoids its pitfalls while generalizing to more than 2 lists for the sake of exercise.  For exactly 2 lists, you could remove the heap handling and simply test which next item is smaller.

```
import heapq

def iter_linear_merge(*args):
  """Yield non-decreasing items from sorted a and b."""
  # Technically, [1, 1, 2, 2] isn't an "increasing" sequence,
  # but it is non-decreasing.

  nexts = []
  for x in args:
    x = iter(x)
    for n in x:
      heapq.heappush(nexts, (n, x))
      break

  while len(nexts) >= 2:
    n, x = heapq.heappop(nexts)
    yield n
    for n in x:
      heapq.heappush(nexts, (n, x))
      break

  if nexts:  # Degenerate case of the heap, not strictly required.
    n, x = nexts[0]
    yield n
    for n in x:
      yield n
```

Instead of the last if-for, the while loop condition could be changed to just "nexts", but it is probably worthwhile to specially handle the last remaining iterator.

If you want to strictly return a list instead of an iterator:

```
def linear_merge(*args):
  return list(iter_linear_merge(*args))
```

Comment: "Popping from a list requires moving all later items". This actually depends on the underlying list implementation. Popping the first element could easily be implemented in O(1), no matter if the implementation is done though a linked list or an array.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: Of course it depends on the underlying list implementation, but we're talking about specific implementations: Python.  What implementation does it differently than I describe?

Comment: This solution is O(nlogn) too and basically just a very elaborate version of `sorted(list1 + list2)
`. Instead of mixing pushing and popping as you do, you could also just push all the items on the heap at once. That makes no difference in terms of time complexity, which is `O(nlogn)` for  constructing a heap. It is true that `list.pop(0)` does not take constant time, but there is a data structure for that: `collections.deque`. Just add `list1, list2 = deque(list1), deque(list2)` to the top of the google solution to make it truely linerar.

Comment: Or just maintain a number that gives the current head of each list instead of using pop ...

Comment: @JochenRitzel: That's the wrong n.  The size of the heap is bounded by the *number of lists* rather than the length of each individual list.  Even though the deque copy is also linear, it takes roughly twice the time for large enough lists.  "Algorithmic complexity is often only a rough guide and always only tells one part of the story."  There are other ways to implement, but I like this one for the sake of the exercise/example.

Answer (score 2):

this could be another soln?
#

```
    def linear_merge(list1, list2):
            tmp = []
            while len(list1) and len(list2):
                    #print list1[-1],list2[-1]
                    if list1[-1] > list2[-1]:
                            tmp.append(list1.pop())
                    else:
                            tmp.append(list2.pop())
                    #print "tmp = ",tmp

            #print list1,list2
            tmp = tmp + list1
            tmp = tmp + list2
            tmp.reverse()
            return tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

With mostly-sorted data, [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) approaches linear. Also, your code doesn't have to screw around with the lists themselves. Therefore, your code is possibly just a bit faster.

But that's what timing is for, innit?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the tutorial is illustrating how to implement a well-known algorithm called 'merge' in Python. The tutorial is not expecting you to actually use a library sorting function in the solution.

sorted() is probably O(nlgn); then your solution cannot be linear in the worst case.

It is important to understand how merge() works because it is useful in many other algorithms. It exploits the fact the input lists are individually sorted, moving through each list sequentially and selecting the smallest option. The remaining items are appended at the end.

The question isn't which is 'quicker' for a given input case but about which algorithm is more complex.

There are hybrid variations of merge-sort which fall back on another sorting algorithm once the input list size drops below a certain threshold.

Comment: You won't have the worst case for sorting, as you are given individually sorted lists.

Comment: Thomas, that depends on the sorting algorithm; there do exist sorts (but maybe they're never actually used in practice these days?) that perform the worst on already-sorted inputs.

Comment: @BrandonCraigRhodes: Of course I could construct a sorting algorithm where this is the worst case, but for which implementations of Python's sorted() is that true?